# How to arrange data for training a 1D CNN model in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have experimental data (in for of 1D vectors of length 9000) of Acoustic sensors from 20 separate events. Five (5) different acoustic sensors are used to capture the data for each event and 5 such set of data are captured in a regular time interval. Thus each event (or class) has 25 such one dimensional vectors (i.e. 5 set of data of 5 different sensors).

Total available data is therefore 500 one dimensional vectors, for all 20 events combined.

How do I arrange this data into training and testing data for training a 1d `CNN` model in `Keras`. Also what should be the format of the labels used for training.

In Keras documentation example given for Stacked LSTM for sequence classification they have created a dummy training dataset as:

```
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
```

and, `input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)`

What does the above two lines mean, specifically what is meant by `data_dim`?

Comment: Well, we can't know what is `data_dim` unless you specify the line where it is initialized. But my bet would be that `data_dim = whatever_input_matrix_you_have.shape()` which is the dimensions of your matrix (`m * n`). `x_train` only seems to be random generated numbers with the size of your real data, in order to initialize your ML model to show you the behavior (as you said : dummy training).

Comment: If you see the Keras documentation example in page  "Guide to Sequential model" in the example of "Stacked LSTM for sequence classification", they have created a dummy data with timesteps = 8 and data_dim = 16 which are later used to create x_train.